# ggplot object value only available after printing it, how do I force it to evaluate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function (not a function that I can modify though) that returns a ggplot2 object, and I would like to access some value of that object. However, the value is `NULL`, but as soon as I print the object it becomes available.

Here is a minimal example that mimics the behaviour of that function

```
test_function <- function(test_arg){ 
      ggplot() + annotate("text", x=0, y=0, label= test_arg) 
    }
```

Now I'd like to extract the value of the label that was set.

```
r$> result <- test_function("test")
r$> result$layers[[1]]$geom_params$label
NULL
```

However

```
r$> print(result)
r$> result$layers[[1]]$geom_params$label
[1] "test"
```

does work as intended.

How can I get the same result, but without actually printing the ggplot object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it lives in the `aes_params` part until the plot gets printed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

test_function <- function(test_arg){ 
  ggplot() + annotate("text", x=0, y=0, label= test_arg) 
} 

result <- test_function("test")

result$layers[[1]]$aes_params$label
#> [1] "test"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! :) Out of curiosity, is there a way to get the behaviour from print, without actually printing it?

Comment: You could build it instead of printing it: `ggplot_build(test_function("test"))$plot$layers[[1]]$geom_params$label`.